# Increasing probability of finding a hash collision

Tags: java, hash, collision, sha1

I'm trying to find a hash collision of my modified hash function. Assuming my modified hash only outputs the first 36 bits of SHA-1. As we know, SHA-1 is a 160-bit hash value, hence, we only need to output 9 characters out of 40 characters for comparison.

How i begin my program is by hashing a string (I have a SHA-1 algorithm running and i will name it as sha1. I have also ensured that the output of the SHA-1 algorithm is correct.)

Firstly, i would hardcode 2 string and extract out 9 characters out of 40 characters since i require only the first 36 bits of SHA-1. The function below basically return a true if a collision is found and false if a collision is not found

```
public static boolean findCollision(int x1, int x2) {

    String message1 = "I tried " + x1 + " iteration to find a collision";
    String message2 = "I tried " + x2 + " iteration to find a collision";       


    //hashing my string and extracting 9 characters
    String message_hash1 = sha1(message1);
    String message_hash2 = sha1(message2);

    String modified_hash1 = message_hash1.substring(0, 9);
    String modified_hash2 = message_hash2.substring(0, 9);

    if (modified_hash1.equals(modified_hash2))  
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Lastly, i will have a main function that will random Integers up to MAX_VALUE in a infinite loop and will break out if and only if a hash is found.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int x1 = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (true) {

        while(true){

            x1 = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            x2 = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            if (x1 != x2) 
                break;  
        } 

        if (findCollision(x1, x2) == true) {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("\nNumber of trials: " + counter);
}
```

If i tried taking only the first 24 bits of SHA-1, i could easily find a collision. However, i'm unable to find a collision for 36 bits instead despite running it for hours. Hence, I'm wondering what is other alternative way for me to find a collision with just 36 bits of SHA-1.

Comment: Buy one (or more) faster computers; run it in parallel.

Comment: The only way to increase the probability that two random 36-bit integers will be equal is to stop them being random.

Comment: It's possible that there are no collisions within the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` range

Comment: I think Mark raised a fair point. why not generate the random string/bytes directly instead of using random numbers to embed in a string?

Comment: The objective of this task is to find a hash collision by using that particular string while making changes to the numbers only. I do understand generating a random string/bytes directly increases the probability of collision but that's not the objective of this case :(

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem i have thought of this problem too. so i ever tried hardcoding the first value as '1' and increasing the other in ascending order. I ran approximately 4 billion iteration but i have yet to find a collision. Hence, i'm guessing there should be an alternative way for me to find a collision since the objective of this task is to obtain a hash collision

Comment: If you do as viz suggested, your program will run faster.  And if there _is_ a collision (which there might not be), you'll find it.  So remove the randomness, and check every combination of integers.  Note that you only need the case where `x2<x1`, so you can make `x2` range from `0` to `x1-1`.  You'll be doing about 1.6 x 10^19 checks, so you'll need all the processing power in China, for the next few centuries.

Comment: To what extent should i check every combination of integer? Do i let the first integer be 1, then check the second integer until the maximum value allowed in java, then change the first integer to 2 and repeat until the first integer becomes the maximum value allowed in java? I really cannot think of any other alternative.

Comment: Well, I don't know whether there are any hash collisions or not.  But if there are, there probably won't be many.  If you trawl systematically through the integers, your computer might turn to dust before you find one.  If you pick integers at random, your computer might turn to dust before you find one.  You choose.

Comment: in another words, if either of the solutions will turn my computer into dust before i find one. is there any no other way? if there's no other way, why would the prof even come out with a task to find a collision? my mate was like suggesting an alternative method which is converting 9 characters into bits then take the first 36 bits of the converted bits and convert back to hex and compare which i doubt it makes any sense to begin with.

Comment: Your professor is trying to teach you how big numbers can be.

Comment: Actually, there's an alternative strategy.  You could record which hash values come up, and note if you get the same one a second time.  This reduces the number of checks you have to do, to a manageable number.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/dawood-ibn-kareem is correct that the optimal method is to remember the previous hashes and check against them, as long as this is practical i.e. fits in memory, and the roughly 2^18 values needed for 36 bit collision do fit in memory, though only a little more (about 50 bits) would not.

This code finds 8 collisions below 2^20 (the first one slightly under 2^18 as expected) in about a second:

```
    static void SO56263762TruncCollision (String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[][] known = new int[1<<24][];
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        for( int i = 0; i < (1<<20); i++ ){
            byte[] raw = sha1.digest(("I tried "+i+" iterations to find a collision").getBytes());
            int key = 0; for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) key = key<<8 | (raw[j]&0xFF);
            char[] val = new char[9]; for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) val[j] = Character.forDigit(j%2==0? (raw[j/2]>>4)&0xF: raw[j/2]&0xF, 16);
            int[] test = known[key]; 
            if( test == null ){ (known[key] = new int[1])[0] = i; }
            else{ 
                for( int k = 0; k < test.length; k++ ){
                    byte[] raw2 = sha1.digest(("I tried "+test[k]+" iterations to find a collision").getBytes());
                    char[] val2 = new char[9]; for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) val2[j] = Character.forDigit(j%2==0? (raw2[j/2]>>4)&0xF: raw2[j/2]&0xF, 16);
                    if( Arrays.equals(val, val2)) System.out.println ("found "+i+" and "+test[k]);
                }
                (known[key] = Arrays.copyOf(test, test.length+1))[test.length] = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("Memory="+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) );
    }
```